# How to access ngModelController in Angular1.5 components?

Tags: angularjs-components

When I use angular.component() to create the brand new component that angular 1.5 provides, there's no link function, so the old way of injecting ngModelController or any other controllers doesn't work.

`require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls)`

The above code is for a directive to access ngModelController.
How do we access it in the component now?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of getting a `ctrls` array, you get them now by name, just like `bindings` use to:

```
class MyComponentController implements ng.IComponentController {

    public modelCtrl: ng.INgModelController;
    ...
    ...
    // use modelCtrl here
    // instead of ctrls[0]
    ...
    ...
}

const MyComponent: ng.IComponentOptions = {
    template: '...',
    bindings: {...},
    require: {modelCtrl: 'ngModel'},
    controller: MyComponentController
}

angular.module('myModule').component('MyComponent', MyComponent);
```

Or, if you prefer plain JS:

```
function MyComponentController() {
    ...
    ...
    // use this.modelCtrl here
    ...
    ...
}

var MyComponent = {
    template: '...',
    bindings: {...},
    require: { modelCtrl: 'ngModel' },
    controller: MyComponentController
};

angular.module('myModule').component('MyComponent', MyComponent);
```

Comment: So I tried this with 1.5.8 and getting access to $pristine, $valid etc. is not possible eg. this.modelCtrl.$pristine is not accessible and an error is thrown that pristine is not accessible on undefined. Can u plz show how we can access $pristine, $valid, $$formatters etc. Using this.modelCtrl ???

Comment: I put a plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/HCmqdowSX0nu0l0au7Ba?p=preview . works like a charm. u rock man !